# How to pick only mp3 files in react-native-document-picker?

Tags: react-native

As in the title. I'm trying to pick mp3 files only, but it seems like on iphone they are not available. Right now I'm picking files this way:

```
  const results = await DocumentPicker.pick({
type: [DocumentPicker.types.audio],
  })
```

But the types are defined like that and i cannot choose anything besides them:

```
  type Types = {
    mimeTypes: {
      allFiles: '*/*',
      audio: 'audio/*',
      images: 'image/*',
      plainText: 'text/plain',
      pdf: 'application/pdf',
      video: 'video/*',
      zip: 'application/zip',
    },
    utis: {
      allFiles: 'public.content',
      audio: 'public.audio',
      images: 'public.image',
      plainText: 'public.plain-text',
      pdf: 'com.adobe.pdf',
      video: 'public.movie',
      zip: 'public.zip-archive',
    },
    extensions: {
      allFiles: '*',
      audio:
        '.3g2 .3gp .aac .adt .adts .aif .aifc .aiff .asf .au .m3u .m4a .m4b .mid .midi .mp2 .mp3 .mp4 .rmi .snd .wav .wax .wma',
      images: '.jpeg .jpg .png',
      plainText: '.txt',
      pdf: '.pdf',
      video: '.mp4',
      zip: '.zip .gz',
    },
  };
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I don't know much about react native, but it seems to me that you can implement your own type object similar to what you posted and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter file types by [common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) on Android and [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) on iOS. So something like this in Javascript should work:

```js
const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
  type: [Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'public.mp3' : 'audio/mpeg'],
});
```

Comment: congratz on hitting 100